# How to find a button's XY coordinates on screen and click at it?

Tags: automation, autokey

I need to find a button's XY coordinates on screen using this button's image and then click at it. I can do this task on windows using AutoHotKey Image search. And I found out that ubuntu AutoHotKey alternative is AutoKey. But I couldn't find a way to do an image search on AutoKey. Does anybody know how to achieve this task?

Answer (score 1):

I think the other answer has missed the point of your question. Instead of determining where your mouse currently is, it seems that you want to find the location of a specific button and press that button.

While I haven't implemented and tested it myself, it sounds like you want to use [`move_to_pat`](https://github.com/autokey/autokey/blob/v0.96.0/lib/autokey/scripting/highlevel.py#L143) or [`click_on_pat`](https://github.com/autokey/autokey/blob/v0.96.0/lib/autokey/scripting/highlevel.py#L123) which seems to use [visgrep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/visgrep).

[Here is a more complete example of use](https://github.com/autokey/autokey/blob/master/new_features.rst#id2)

Comment: AutoKey has a limited Visgrep() API that you can see in our current (0.96.0) [documentation](http://autokey.github.io/autokey/api/highlevel.html). It supports a single level search. If you need the nested search to find an image within a larger image, then you have to call visgrep() with a subprocess.check() function to be able to use all the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the current mouse coordinates with `xdotool`:

```
xdotool getmouselocation
```

For use in a script, use

```
eval $(xdotool getmouselocation --shell)
```

This will create shell variables you can easily retrieve elsewhere in a script:

```
echo $X $Y
```

will print the coordinated.

*Caveat* this only works when you use Xorg (but then, also Autokey works only on Xorg).